# NSURL Error in XCode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, nsurl

*BEGINNER ALERT! Please talk to me like I'm a 5-year-old because I am new to this platform and language. I will be grateful and unoffended.*

I have the following code in my Xcode project to open a website in the native browser from a button on the app home page:

```
@IBAction func faceURL(_ sender: Any) {
    NSURL *spotiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com"];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:faceURL options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success){
            NSLog(@"Opened url");
        }   
    }];
}
```

On the line:

```
NSURL *spotiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com"];
```

it's throwing the following error:

> Expected "," separator Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ";"

It recommends putting a `;` between the colon and `@` symbol before the URL. I know some of this is deprecated with the new Xcode and Swift format, but I can't find a straightforward answer for this particular issue. Thank you in advance for your wisdom.

*UPDATE*

Thank you to the folks who helped with this. In case anyone else comes across this issue, here is the code that ended up working to touch the button and open a URL in the native browser:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@IBAction func openURL(_ sender: Any) {
let openURL = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")
UIApplication.shared.open(openURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I also had to delete the original button and corresponding reference in the ViewController, replace the button, and do a fresh connection with ViewController to get it working. Many thanks!

Comment: Apparently you copy paste is at its best, you just copied an objective c snippet for the creation of the nsurl object inside a function in a swift syntax, you re lucky your mac didnt explode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use Objective C code in a Swift method. If your project is written in Swift then this is (probably) the code you need:

```
@IBAction func faceURL(_ sender: Any) {

    if let facebookURL = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")
    {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(facebookURL) // the open method you were using doesn't exist in Swift
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you work through a few tutorials to learn the basics of iOS development.

Comment: The method he was using exists and compiles but is only available in iOS 10 hence a `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {}else{}` is needed

Comment: Thank you @JedSoane This got rid of the error message and allowed me to compile and run on the simulator. When I click the button it's crashing tho. "THREAD 1: Signal SIGABRT" pops up in the AppDelegate file next to the line: "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {" Any ideas on why that would happen? This is like greek to me but I'm learning!

Comment: @D.W. I would guess that you button is connected to a method that doesn't exist (for instance if you renamed the IBAction method then the button will still be linked to the old method name and you will get a SIGABRT). If you are using storyboards then open the storyboard, select the button, delete the old connection and create a new one linking to the new method.

Comment: Thank you very much. I replaced the original button and did a fresh build. Between that and the code revisions I've got it working now. Posting my functional code above.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** you have `faceURL` in `openURL` when it should be `spotiURL`.

**Second:** you mean to convert the code you copied from SO from Obj-C to Swift which I will do for you :)

```
let spotiURL = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")
UIApplication.shared.openURL(spotiURL!)
```

Comment: The question is tagged correctly. The problem is that the OP doesn't know that they copy and pasted Objective-C code into their Swift file.

Comment: Thank you, @Mentos. This seems to work except for the exclamation mark in the line below is throwing an error: UIApplication.shared.openURL(spotiURL!)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are mixing Swift (first line) and ObjC (all the other) syntax, so you have to choose one of them first of all. Your "mixed" code looks good btw.

Comment: Thanks @Zeb. Working on parsing down multiple proposed solutions to this functionality issue.